# Is it possible to disable CTabItem in CTabFolder?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I have created such CTabFolder in swt:

```java
folder = new CTabFolder(group, SWT.PUSH);
```

and added some items:

```java
CTabItem tab1 = new CTabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
CTabItem tab2 = new CTabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
CTabItem tab3 = new CTabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);

tab1.setText("Tab 1");
tab2.setText("Tab 2");
tab3.setText("Tab 3");

tab1.setControl(CreateFirstGroup(folder, "Type 1"));
tab2.setControl(CreateFirstGroup(folder, "Type 2"));
tab3.setControl(CreateFirstGroup(folder, "Type 3"));
```

and I'm trying to disable items of this group:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < folder.getChildren().length; i++) {
    folder.getChildren()[i].setEnabled(false);
}
```

but all tabs are still clickable. Maybe it is possible to enable/disable items?

Comment: @greg-449, but as I see this method is availble for selection :( Maybe you can suggest another variant of achieving my aim? I'm very newbie in jface))

Comment: I have managed to do it :) Maybу it is a trick of bad style but I solved my problem :D